# Publish additional external jar-files to ossrh with maven

Tags: maven

I want to publish my projects artifacts with maven to nexus. Therefore I followed [this](https://central.sonatype.org/publish/publish-maven) documentation which works for me for artifacts which are also build with maven. But now I want to publish additional artifacts (*.tgz files) which I download from somewhere else. I have not yet found out how to express in maven terms that I want to deploy those "local" artifacts.

What I tried is:

- Create a new staging repo on ossrh with the pom file. This works and a new, open staging repository is created containing the pom file and a signature file.

```
> mvn deploy -DrepositoryId=ossrh
```

- upload additional resources. This fails

```
> mvn deploy:deploy-file -Dfile=test-tst-0.0.1_linux-ppc64le_bin.tar.gz -Dclassifier=linux-ppc64le -DrepositoryId=ossrh -Durl=https://s01.oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/iosapmachine-1031 -DgroupId=io.sapmachine -DartifactId=test-tst -Dversion=0.0.1
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] 
[INFO] -----------------------< io.sapmachine:test-tst >-----------------------
[INFO] Building io.sapmachine:test-tst 0.0.1
[INFO] --------------------------------[ pom ]---------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-deploy-plugin:2.7:deploy-file (default-cli) @ test-tst ---
Uploading to ossrh: https://s01.oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/iosapmachine-1031/io/sapmachine/test-tst/0.0.1/test-tst-0.0.1-linux-ppc64le.gz
Uploading to ossrh: https://s01.oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/iosapmachine-1031/io/sapmachine/test-tst/0.0.1/test-tst-0.0.1.pom
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  5.002 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2021-12-08T09:02:40+01:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.7:deploy-file (default-cli) on project test-tst: Failed to deploy artifacts: Could not find artifact io.sapmachine:test-tst:gz:linux-ppc64le:0.0.1 in ossrh (https://s01.oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/iosapmachine-1031) -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

My pom.xml looks like this:

```
> cat pom.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<groupId>io.sapmachine</groupId>
<artifactId>test-tst</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1</version>

<name>${project.groupId}:${project.artifactId}</name>
<description>Test</description>

<packaging>pom</packaging>
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<url>https://test.io/</url>

<licenses>
    <license>
        <name>GPLv2 + Classpath Exception</name>
        <url>https://test/LICENSE</url>
    </license>
</licenses>

<distributionManagement>
    <snapshotRepository>
        <id>ossrh</id>
        <url>https://s01.oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots</url>
    </snapshotRepository>
    <repository>
        <id>ossrh</id>
        <url>https://s01.oss.sonatype.org/service/local/staging/deploy/maven2</url>
    </repository>
</distributionManagement>

<developers>
    <developer>
        <name>Test</name>
        <email>test@test.com</email>
        <organization>Test AG</organization>
        <organizationUrl>http://www.test.com</organizationUrl>
    </developer>
</developers>

<scm>
    <connection>scm:git:https://github.com/test/tree/test-${project.version}</connection>
    <url>http://github.com/test/tree/test-${project.version}</url>
</scm>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-gpg-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>sign-artifacts</id>
                    <phase>verify</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>sign</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
</project>
>
```

Comment: Your file `test-tst-0.0.1_linux-ppc64le_bin.tar.gz` is not following maven/repository naming convention. The first part `test-tst-0.0.1` is ok..but the rest `_linux-ppc64le_bin.tar.gz` the way to go is to name it: test-tst-0.0.1-linux-ppc64le-bin.tar.gz` where `linux-ppc64le-bin` is a so called classifier..also the question why deploying not via `mvn deploy` instead of calling goals manually...

Comment: I tried your proposal and this lead to:
`[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.7:deploy-file (default-cli) on project test-tst: Failed to deploy artifacts: Could not find artifact io.sapmachine:test-tst:gz:linux-ppc64le:0.0.1 in ossrh (https://s01.oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/iosapmachine-1031)`

Comment: Regarding the second question: I would of course love to upload everything in one shot. But when going through the 'mvn deploy' documentation I couldn't find explicit parameters where I could specify on commandline additional artifacts, their filenames, classifiers and extensions. I can upload my project through the ossrh ui (https://s01.oss.sonatype.org/#stagingRepositories) and there I have to specify these 3 infos for each resource I upload. But I was not able to write a pom.xml where my local resources are mentioned in the pom.xml and are deployed correctly